What are the rules for releasing a game on Steam?
Google Play Store has a developer policy which states the rules on releasing a game there. Apple's App Store has App Review Guideline which state the rules on releasing a game there.
What about Steam? What are the rules on releasing a game on Steam? I tried searching for them on the Internet, but didn't find anything.

First, Steam has the page "Getting Started documentation". Here is the link: https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/gettingstarted
This first site above shows you very detailed info on how to create an account, download SDK, build the app, upload the app, set the price, etc...

Second, Steam provides lots of useful info on rules, regulations, payment account, tax, fee, etc... Here is the link: https://partner.steamgames.com/steamdirect
Specifically, this second site shows their rules as follows:
What you shouldn’t publish on Steam:

Hate speech, i.e. speech that promotes hatred, violence or
discrimination against groups of people based on ethnicity,
religion, gender, age, disability or sexual orientation
Sexually explicit images of real people
Adult content that isn’t appropriately labeled and age-gated
Libelous or defamatory statements
Content you don’t own or have adequate rights to
Content that violates the laws of any jurisdiction in which it will
be available
Content that is patently offensive or intended to shock or disgust
viewers
Content that exploits children in any way
Applications that modify customer’s computers in unexpected or
harmful ways, such as malware or viruses
Applications that fraudulently attempts to gather sensitive
information, such as Steam credentials or financial data (e.g.
credit card information)
Video content not directly related to a product that has shipped on
Steam.
Non-interactive 360 VR Videos
Applications built on blockchain technology that issue or allow
exchange of cryptocurrencies or NFTs.

